# Quote about errors in math writing

Tags: ho.history-overview, soft-question

I'm searching for the original reference of a quote that went something like:

"Errors in a mathematics text add an element of surprise to an otherwise predictable plot."

I believe it may have been from the 1700s or 1800s.

Answer (score 3):

A resource might be

Maurice Lecat, Erreurs de mathématiciens des origines à nos jours, Bruxelles : Castaigne, 1935

Cheers, Scott

Comment: @Scott: 1+! Good result!